# JSON.stringify on Arrays adding numeric keys for each array value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, rhino, stringify

I am trying to convert an array to object .

Below is the array value which I am trying to transform into an object.

```
kbInfo : [{ "questionId": "1", "customQuestion": "What is your first car make and model", "answer": "Ford Pinto" },{ "questionId": "14", "customQuestion": "Your favorite sports", "answer": "Sleeping" } ]
```

This gives a result like below after doing a JSON.stringify(kbaInfo)

```
{"0":{ "questionId": "1", "customQuestion": "What is your first car make and model", "answer": "Ford Pinto" },"1":{ "questionId": "14", "customQuestion": "Your favorite sports", "answer": "Sleeping" }}
```

I want to create the result in this form.

```
{ "SQA": [{ "questionId": "1", "customQuestion": "What is your first car make and model", "answer": "Ford Pinto" }, { "questionId": "14", "customQuestion": "Your favorite sports", "answer": "Sleeping" } ]}
```

I am not able to figure out how I can create on object result like above. I am using a Rhino 1.7 engine. Is there a way I can achieve this form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you mean that `kbInfo` and `kbaInfo` are the same variable. To get that "SQA" property in your output object, you'll need to create it...

For example:

```js
var kbInfo = [{ "questionId": "1", "customQuestion": "What is your first car make and model", "answer": "Ford Pinto" },{ "questionId": "14", "customQuestion": "Your favorite sports", "answer": "Sleeping" } ];

var wrapped = { SQA: kbInfo };

console.log(JSON.stringify(wrapped));
```

From comments it seems that your input data might not be an array, but just an "array-like" object. In that case, create an array from it. This solution assumes that the input object has a `length` property:

```js
var kbInfo = { 0: { "questionId": "1", "customQuestion": "What is your first car make and model", "answer": "Ford Pinto" }, 1: { "questionId": "14", "customQuestion": "Your favorite sports", "answer": "Sleeping" }, length: 2 };

var wrapped = { SQA: Array.from(kbInfo) };

console.log(JSON.stringify(wrapped));
```

Comment: Its still including numeric key when I do a JSON.stringify it is still creating the result in this form {"SQA": {"0":{ "questionId": "1", "customQuestion": "What is your first car make and model", "answer": "Ford Pinto" },"1":{ "questionId": "14", "customQuestion": "Your favorite sports", "answer": "Sleeping" }}}

Comment: Did you run the snippet? It doesn't give that output that you mention in your comment.

Comment: Yes I don't know why those numeric keys are getting inserted.

Comment: Please provide a runnable snippet that reproduces your output. For instance on jsfiddle.net Most likely your `kbInfo` is **not** an array, but then please provide what you **do** have instead.

Comment: I added a solution for when your input is not an array, but has index properties **and** a `length` property.

Comment: @Karu where are you getting the value for `kbInfo` from? I think that is the source of your challenge, getting an object with numeric keys, instead of an Array

Comment: @trincot I understood the issue. I was under wrong assumption that I was passed an object. Instead, the passed value for kbInfo was already in a string form which meant that when I did stringify on a string, the numeric keys got inserted. The approach I followed then was to get an object from the kbInfo string by using JSON.parse() and then doing a JSON.stringify on it. Your solution is correct. My question was not framed with the correct info. Thanks for your help.